# Default user and password in uchiwa with sensu

Tags: sensu

I'm trying to deploy sensu-server in my local ubuntu with uchiwa dashboard. When I end all config and start uchiwa, I try to access from other computer in my local net, with local ip and 3000 port. Uchiwa ask me user and password combination that Im not created in my uchiwa.json file any user or password. This is it:

```
{
"sensu": [
    {
        "name": "Sensu",
        "host": "localhost",
        "ssl": false,
        "user": "",
        "pass": "",
        "port": 4567,
        "path": "",
        "timeout": 5000
    }
],
"uchiwa": {
    "host": "192.168.1.18",
    "port": 3000,
    "stats": 10,
    "refresh": 10000
}
}
```

I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you did, I missed it too:

my `/etc/sensu/conf.d/uchiwa.json` file contained the following:

```
{
    "sensu": [
        {
            "name": "Sensu",
            "host": "localhost",
            "ssl": false,
            "port": 4567,
            "path": "",
            "timeout": 5000
        }
    ],
    "uchiwa": {
        "port": 3000,
        "stats": 10,
        "refresh": 10000
    }
}
```

But you might notice that there is another default `uchiwa.json` file located in `/etc/sensu/`

In this `uchiwa.json` file it gives the username as "admin" and the password as "secret" which you might find to work for you.

Also, please note that if you are following the directions from [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-sensu-monitoring-rabbitmq-and-redis-on-ubuntu-14-04) They aren't 100% correct.  I had to move my newly created `uchiwa.json` file from `/etc/sensu/conf.d` to `/etc/sensu` because that is where uchiwa is looking for the configuration file according to `/var/log/uchiwa.err`

If you truly want no password here is what should work:

1. move the `/etc/sensu/uchiwa.json` file by renaming it to `uchiwa.json.old`

   `mv /etc/sensu/uchiwa.json /etc/sensu/uchiwa.json.old`
2. move the `/etc/sensu/conf.d/uchiwa.json` file to `/etc/sensu/uchiwa.json`

   ```
   cd /etc/sensu/conf.d && mv uchiwa.json ../
   ```
3. restart the uchiwa service

   ```
   service uchiwa restart
   ```

This way you can get to `http://<ipaddress>:3000` and not be prompted for a password.

---

I think I found where uchiwa is pulling from:

in `/etc/init.d/uchiwa`

The following line:

```
args="-c /etc/sensu/uchiwa.json -p /opt/uchiwa/src/public"
```

Can be altered to reflect the path to your `uchiwa.json` file, then you can restart the uchiwa service.